# bool function doesn't work as a while condition

Tags: c++

I am trying to to check if a file has successfully opened, read from it and output what I've read from it all in one function, because I have 7 files to operate on in the same code and I want to avoid writing the same code over and over again.

So I have made a `bool` function and put it as a `while` condition.

If I succeed, the function returns `true` and if I don't it returns `false`. So a `while(!function)` should keep trying until it works, correct ? And the answer is yes, it works as intended.

But if I change the condition of the while to `while(function)` one would expect to repeat the function until it fails somehow (maybe it can't open the file.). But it doesn't behave as expected. It only works correctly on the first `while` iteration.

This is the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

bool readConfig(std::fstream& file, std::string (&str)[10], std::string identity) {
  if(file.is_open()) {
    if(file.seekg(0)) {
      std::cout<<"Start from 0"<<std::endl;
    }
    // Get content line by line of txt file
    int i = 0;
    while(getline(file, str[i++]));
    std::cout<<"i= "<<i<<std::endl;
    for(int k = 0; k<i; k++) {
    std::cout<<identity<<" = "<<str[k]<<std::endl;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    std::cout<<"ERROR ! Could not open file."<<std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {

    char configFilePath[]="test.txt";
    std::fstream configFile;

    configFile.open(configFilePath, std::fstream::in);
    std::string test[10];
    std::string id = "testing";
    while(!readConfig(configFile, test,id)) {
        usleep(1000*1000);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

This is the content of `test.txt` :

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

This is the output:

```
Start from 0
i= 5
testing = line 1
testing = line 2
testing = line 3
testing = line 4
testing = 
i= 1
testing = line 1
i= 1
testing = line 1
```

and so on.

Why does it work on the first iteration but then it stops at `i=1` ? I am asking because I don't know if what I did is correct or not. `while(!function)` works, but maybe it won't work all the time, maybe my code is flawed.

Or maybe `while(getline(configFile, string[i++]));` is at fault here ?

This is the code I am trying to replace:

```
void readConfig(std::fstream& configFile, std::string (&str)[10], std::string identity) {
  if(configFile) {
    // Get content line by line of txt file
    int i = 0;
    while(getline(configFile, str[i++]));
    //for debug only
    if((i-1) == 0) {
      std::cout<<identity<<" = "<<str[i-1]<<std::endl;
    } else {
      for(int k = 0; k<i-1; k++) {
        std::cout<<identity<<" = "<<str[k]<<std::endl;
      }
    }
  } else {
    log("ERROR ! Could not get content from file.");
  }
}

int main() {
file.open(file, std::fstream::in);
    if(file.is_open()) {
      std::cout<<"Successfully opened URL Display Text file."<<std::endl;
      std::string inputs[10];
      std::string id = "url_text";
      readConfig(file, inputs, id);
      file.close();
    } else {
      // Could not open file
      log("Error ! Could not open file.");
    }
}
```

I do this 7 times, instead of just calling a function 7 times, that does all of that.

Comment: You seem to expect the function to read the file from the beginning every time, but for it to happen you either need to reopen the file, or use `.seekg(0)`.

Comment: Please add the necessary includes and please don't name a function parameter `string`. At least name it something like `str`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But if it doesn't read the file from the beginning why is the output `line 1`, which is the first line of the file. Where to use `.seekg(0)` ? Put it after `if(file.is_open()) { like` this: `file.seekg(0);` ?

Comment: @nikoksr Done and done. I don't see why should those pose any problem, but ok.

Comment: @bleah1 the added includes help us help you and help people in the future follow the possible solution. And I don't need to explain why it's bad practice to share names between your argument and a member of the popular std namespace.

Comment: @bleah1 *"why is the output `line 1`"* Because your loop condition is wrong. It should be `k<i-1` rather than `k<i`, since `while(getline(file, str[i++]));` increments `i` even on a failed read.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know that. But if I do `k<i-1`, when `i=1` the `for` won't work, because `k<i-1` means `k<0`. So, from the second iteration onward there will be no output, because `i` remains at 1. Also, I have edited the question.

Comment: @bleah1 *"from the second iteration onward there will be no output"* And that behavior would be completely correct, since you've read all lines on the first iteration. There are no more lines to read on the subsequent iterations. *"I have edited the question"* Does the code work now when you added `seekg`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok. If that is correct, then it means that if I use `while(!function)` with `readConfig` as it is right now it will work correctly, yes ?

Comment: @bleah1 Try it and see if it works. You still need to modify the loop condition, but otherwise I don't see any obvious errors.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Which loop condition ? If you are referring to the `for` it's been taken care of. Read what I've wrote above in the comments. I have done `k<i` just for this example.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @TobySpeight That is the minimal example that I made for this question alone.

Comment: No, it's not minimal at all.  It seems to rely on an external file, for one thing.  That should almost never be necessary in an example.  Please reduce it to just the part you're asking about.

Comment: @TobySpeight But I am having issues with files and how to read from them and how to do that neat and cleanly by using a bool function.

Comment: You can make a self-contained program if you use a `std::istringstream` rather than a `std::fstream`, for example.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't know how to do that. This is my current level. That is what doesn't work for me and I don't know what to strip away from the code.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I change the condition of the while to while(function) one would expect to repeat the function until it fails somehow (maybe it can't open the file.).

You reasoning is off here. The function is not opening the file, so that is nothing that can go wrong on the next iteration when it suceeded on the first.

What the function does is: it reads all the contets of the file, then returns `true`. And subsequent iterations there is nothing left to read, but still the function returns `true`.

You should check if the file is open only once, not in each iteration. If the function is supposed to read a single line then make it so, currently it reads all.

Comment: The function is supposed to read all the lines from the file and place them in that `string array`. I want to keep trying to open the file if it fails. That's why I've put the `file read` inside a `bool function` inside a `while`.

Comment: @bleah1 see last edit. The function does read all contents of the file, but you only use the last line read by `getline`, why did you place `getline` inside the while?

Comment: @bleah1 why do you want to keep trying to open the file when it failed? Once it failed there is no reason to assume the next open call will suceed. Also you only have a single `open` in the code and that is outside of any loop

Comment: @bleah1 ...hence you also dont have to check inside a loop if it was sucessfully openend. You check it once and if it isnt opened you dont even have to enter the loop

Comment: I have the `getline` inside a `while` loop because that's how I read a file line by line.
That's the method I found online, on SO actually.

Comment: Before trying to put the `read file` inside a `function` inside a `while` I had them in simple `ifs`. `if(file.is_open()) { //good} else {//file did not open}`. And I have 7 files to open and check if they've opened, and read from them if they've opened. I wanted to make 1 function for all the files and not to repeat the same process 7 times. Why write the same code 7 times ?

Comment: @bleah1 but you reall **all** the file with the loop. If you want a single line drop the `while` or put the loop around the code where you put the line in the array

Comment: @bleah1 I tried to focus on problems in your code, for how to do it in a different way maybe better see the other answer

Comment: But I want ALL the lines. I want to read the whole file. From start to end. And I am already doing that with `while(getline(file, string[i++]));`

Comment: @bleah1 omg sorry misread your code... the part of "reading all the lines" is wrong. but the part "once you read all you cannot read more" is still correct

Comment: @bleah1 thats a different question now. If you have a different question better open a new one.

Comment: @bleah1 anyhow it is not clear why you "do this 7 times" you can already call the function you have there 7 times...

Answer (score 1):

Change the test from `if (file.is_open())` to `if (file)`. Failing to open the file is not the only way that a file stream can end up in a bad state. In particular, on the second call to this function, the stream is open, but it's in a failed state because the last read attempt failed.

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate with examples and specify which are first and second call.

Comment: In the first call to your function, the calls to `getline` eventually failed, because there was no more text to read. That doesn't close the file, so `file.is_open()` still returns true. But the file is not readable, because of the earlier failure. `if (file)` tests whether the file is readable, not just whether it's open. And that's the test you need. **Try it**.

Comment: Now it fails on the second iteration. I suppose that's how it should be, because of `getline`.

Comment: Yes, it should fail on the second iteration. The stream is still in its error state, because the last attempted read failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the file line by line, print the lines and store them, I'd do it like this.

- Rather than using a c-style array use a `std::vector` or `std::array`
- Check the if the file is open before you call the read function

  ```
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>

  void readConfig(std::ifstream& configFile,
                  std::vector<std::string>& lines,
                  const unsigned int limit) {
      std::string line;

      while (std::getline(configFile, line)) {
          if (lines.size() >= limit) {
              break;
          }
          lines.push_back(line);
      }
  }

  int main() {
      const std::array<std::string, 3> fileNames = {"test1.txt", 
                                                    "test2.txt", 
                                                    "test3.txt"};

      // Iterate over all your files
      for (const auto& fileName : fileNames) {
          // Open the file
          std::ifstream configFile(fileName);

          if (!configFile.is_open()) {
              std::cout << "ERROR! Could not open file.\n";
              continue;
          }

          // Read the file
          std::vector<std::string> lines;
          constexpr unsigned int limit = 4;
          readConfig(configFile, lines, limit);

          if (configFile.is_open()) {
              configFile.close();
          }

          // Work with the file content
          std::cout << fileName << "\n";
          for (const auto& line : lines) {
              std::cout << "testing = " << line << "\n";
          }
          std::cout << "\n";
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Before trying to put the read file inside a function inside a while I had them in simple ifs: `if(file.is_open()) { //good} else {//file did not open}`. And I have 7 files to open and check if they've opened, and read from them if they've opened. I wanted to make 1 function for all the files and not to repeat the same process 7 times. Why write the same code 7 times ?

Comment: So, I have already done what you've told me. I am trying to make it so that I don't have to repeat code every time for each file.

Comment: @bleah1 You can easily use that code to iterate over a multitude of files. I edited my answer for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your output paints a fairly clear picture of what is going on. You have enough debugging output to identify what choices have been made. They key point I would focus on is the following sequence:

> ```
> testing = 
> i= 1
> ```

The first of these lines is the fifth line read from your four-line file. Not surprisingly, there is nothing there. The next output line comes from the next invocation of `readConfig`, somewhere in the branch where `file.isopen()` is true. However, note that there is *not* a line saying "Start from 0" between these two. That means `file` converted to `false` after the call to `file.seekg(0)` (the value returned by that function is `file`, not directly a boolean). This indicates some sort of error state, and one should expect that error state to persist until cleared. And there is no attempt made to clear it.

The next bit of code is the `getline` loop. As with `seekg`, the `getLine` function returns the stream (`file`) rather than a boolean. As expected, the error state has persisted, making the loop condition `false`, hence no iterations of the loop.

> ```
> testing = line 1
> ```

The next line of output is ambiguous. It could indicate that the position was successfully changed to the start of the file, and that the first line of input was successfully read. Or it could indicate that the call to `getLine` returned before erasing the provided string, leaving the contents from the first call to `readConfig`. I'm thinking the latter, but you could check for yourself by manually erasing `str[0]` before the `getline` loop.

In general, reusing resources like this makes debugging harder because the results could be misleading. Debugging would be less confusing if `str` was a local variable instead of a parameter. Similar for `file` – instead of a stream parameter, you could pass a string with the name of the file to open.